# Chrome miniwindows not working

Tags: google-chrome, browser, 23.04

I just bought a Dell XPS Plus 9320, and I'm running 23.04 on it. I'm having a weird issue where chrome is not displaying pages with miniwindows correctly. What I mean by a miniwindow is when a page loads a layer in front of the main layer. For example, in google docs or google sheets, when you change the share settings on a document, it opens a little layer in front of your doc where you specify who you want to share it with it.

On my machine, when one of those miniwindows opens, it hangs. This also happens on amazon when I try to use the "buy it now" button, and in a bunch of other contexts as well. I've tried purging chrome completely, deleting all cache and user data etc, and reinstalling it, but the problem persists. The problem doesn't occur with eg firefox. I'd really like to continue using chrome, since I use google for password storage etc, but this means a good amount of websites become unusable for very common operations.

Here's a screenshot of what it does when I try to use "buy now" on amazon. It just hangs like this.

[image]

Comment: Are your pop-ups allowed in the Chrome settings in Privacy and security -> Site Settings ->  Pop-ups and redirects?

Comment: pop-ups weren't allowed, but enabling them didn't change anything. It's not pop-ups exactly that are the problem, but rather the kind of browser dialog windows that open as a layer in front of a page.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.  Somethings to possibly look at could be swap file settings, memory available during this time, or maybe a setting in `chrome://flags/` like hardware rendering but that can also be in the Chrome Settings themselves.  I have seen where disabling hardware rendering in Chrome has solved other pages not loading like Google Maps.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Interestingly, the image I put into the OP also doesn't show up when I load this page from my xps, but does show up in chrome on my phone.